# Is there something similiar to :is pseduo-class in scss?

Tags: css, sass

Is there something similar to `:is` pseudo-class in scss? Without using `&`, and nesting. Linter in my current project complains if I use `:is`.

```css
input:is([type=text],[type=password]).input {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" />
<input type="password" class="input" />
```

Comment: Isn't SCSS just a superset of CSS? So anything that's valid CSS is also valid SCSS...

Comment: Please just share the code you have in the CodePen here on Stack Overflow. We have Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) which will do HTML/CSS easily enough. SCSS compiles to CSS, so you'd need something in CSS Level 2 that would do the same thing as `:is`, which is unlikely, although you can get some support via `:matches` and `:any`. See [MDN for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is).

Comment: I was not sure if stackoverflow snippets support `:is`. I'll add a snippet to my post

Answer (score 0):

I've found one solution for my question, I can just update my `.stylelintrc` by adding this.

```
"selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown": [ true, {
  "ignorePseudoClasses": ["is"],
}],
```

But anyway, this answers my question only partially. What if I want to support ancient browsers, and want something similar to `:is` but in scss, I've been thinking about implementing my own scss function.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it just be the SCSS nesting with the [parent selector (`&`)](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector)?  For instance...

```css
input:is([type=text],[type=password]).input {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

...rewritten in CSS *without* using the `:is` would be

```css
[type=text].input,
[type=password].input {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

...which seems like it should be able to be rewritten as a nested Sass rule as:

```
[type=text], [type=password] {
  &.input {
    border: 5px solid red;
  }
}
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding your requirements, this seems like it would fit for at least the use case you provided as an example.

Comment: Yeah, nesting works, but I was looking for something more like a function, or maybe mixin. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that matches in [the `sass:selector` function docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/selector).  You _might_ be able to write your own sass function or mix-in. Why do you want to avoid using nesting?

Comment: Like this for example
@function is($before, $middle, $after)

And the function call
is('input', '[type=text], [type=password]', '.input')

Comment: Nah nesting works fine, right now when I'm thinking about it, after you provided the example.

Comment: @antlis - sure-- I'm guessing one could write a function similar to that-- in order to allow for an indeterminate number of inputs you'd probably need to pass certain values as [lists](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists).